# Get the path of the Image in Mathematica

Tags: image

When copying the Image from the hard drive to the Mathematica notebook, what can I do to have the path of the Image?

I tried `Imort[img] // Path` where `img` is Image but it didn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the name to find the path, but not the image variable.

```
name = "image.png";
img = Import[name]
FindFile[name]
```

`FindFile` finds the same file that `Import` finds.  If you have another image with the same name in a different directory, by changing to that directory (with `SetDirectory`) `Import` and `FindFile` will find the second image.

Comment: I don't know the name, I just drag and drop the image to the notebook.

Comment: Then you have copied the image and the path information has gone.

Comment: So not to loose the path info, I need to import it not to copy?

Comment: Yes, that's the usual way.

Comment: In that case what is the point to use FindFile, if you know the name?

Comment: Like `Import`, "`FileFind[name]` successively searches for a file with the specified name in each of the directories given in `$Path`." (See the documentation [Details](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindFile.html).)  So you may just know the file name, but not the file path.